# How to hide a jpg file in a disk image starting at a particular offset?

Tags: linux

Disk image name: Alienimage.dd
Picture to be hidden in the disk image: picture1.jpg

The picture needs to be hidden starting at offset 1MB of the disk image. The rest of the disk image remains unmodified. What LINUX commands can i use?

Here is the fdisk of the image file:

```
root@kali:/media/sf_Kali_Shared/AlienImage# fdisk -l alienimage.dd

Disk alienimage.dd: 216.9 MiB, 227409920 bytes, 444160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6f20736b

Device         Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
alienimage.dd1       778135908 1919645538 1141509631 544.3G 72 unknown
alienimage.dd2       168689522 2104717761 1936028240 923.2G 65 Novell Netware 386
alienimage.dd3      1869881465 3805909656 1936028192 923.2G 79 unknown
alienimage.dd4               0 3637226495 3637226496   1.7T  d unknown

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: You can use dd, which has options to seek in the target device/file before writing.

Comment: I think this is the answer when you want to use ``dd``: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146923

Comment: Which partition is `picture1.jpg` on? What is the full path to the file within that filesystem?

Comment: If the partition holds a valid filesystem, then you can mount it with `-o loop` and `-o offset=${OFFSET}`. Once mounted, erase / delete the file as appropriate.

Comment: That said, the MBR appears to be somewhat wonky (partition 4 is over the top of the others).

Answer (score 0):

Given this picture and this disk image

```
$ cat catpic

 ^ ^
>'.'<
(U U)

$ wc -c catpic # need this later to extract image
18 catpic

$ cat diskimage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
```

We insert the image into the diskimage at offset 100 bytes

```
$ dd if=catpic of=diskimage bs=1 seek=100 conv=notrunc
18+0 records in
18+0 records out
18 bytes (18 B) copied, 8.5e-05 seconds, 212 kB/s
```

We prove the image is stored inside the diskimage, then we extract it

```
$ cat diskimage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
 ^ ^
>'.'<
(U U)
iqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea

$ dd if=diskimage bs=1 skip=100 count=18 2>/dev/null

 ^ ^
>'.'<
(U U)
```

---

Notes

For bigger files you will want to increase `bs` substantially.